# Compare system date with a date field in SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to compare a date record in SQL Server with the system date. In my example the user first register with his name and date of birth which are then stored in the database. The user than logs into the web application using his name only. After logging in, his name is shown on the side where it says `"Welcome "player name`" using `Sessions`.

What I am trying to show in addition to his name is a message saying "happy birthday" if his date of birth matches the system date. I have tried working with `System.DateTime.Now`, but what I think is that it is also comparing the year, and what I really want is the day and the month only. I would really appreciate any suggestion or help.

CODE In Login page:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  String name = TextBox1.Text;
  String date = System.DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
  SqlConnection myconn2 = new 
    SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["User"].ToString()); 

  SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
  SqlDataReader reader;

  myconn2.Open();
  cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select D_O_B from User WHERE Username = @username", 
                        myconn2);
  cmd2.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = name;
  cmd2.Connection = myconn2                           
  cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
  reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
  while (reader.Read().ToString() == date)
  {
    Session["Birthday"] = "Happy Birthday";
  }
}
```

Note: I using the same reader in the code above this one, but the reader here is with a different connection. Also, `reader.Read()` is different than `reader.HasRows`?

Code in Web app Page:

```
string date = (string)(Session["Birthday"]); // Retrieving the session
Label6.Text = date;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the code fragment to compare date above with this one

```
object dobVal = null;
while ((dobVal= reader.Read()) != null)
{
  var storedDob = Convert.ToDateTime(dobVal.ToString());

  if(storedDob.Month == DateTime.Now.Month && 
     storedDob.Day == DateTime.Now.Day)
  {
    Session["Birthday"] = "Happy Birthday";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, What if the code fragment from `myconn2.Open();` till the end was part of `else` in an `IF` statement ? I tried it, while pressing the button nothing happens ?

Comment: @JeT_BluE You replace your code while (reader.Read().ToString() == date)
  {
    Session["Birthday"] = "Happy Birthday";
  } with my one

Comment: @JeT_BluE  Looking at your code I found that you should remove cmd2.Connection = myconn2                           
  cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
as well. They are redundant

Comment: @DrakeVN I replaced, when I press the button nothing happens.

Comment: @JeT_BluE First try to look at your DB, if the user with the DOB exists? Second, remove the redundant code 
cmd2.Connection = myconn2                           
  cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: @DrakeVN I did remove the duplication thanks. I checked the date it exists to today's date so that I can try it. When I press the button the page stays still it doesn't load or do anything.

Comment: @JeT_BluE The navigation of you page isn't related to the code determining the DOB. If you want to move to the app page after clicking the button, you must call either Response.Redirect(YourAppPage) or Server.Transfer(YourAppPage).

Comment: @DrakeVN I already have the `Response.Redirect(AppPage)` in place which means that when the user enters his name, he will press login and at pressing login, compare his DOB (in database) with `System.Date` (month and day), create a session "happy birthday" if both dates match and then retrieve it in the AppPage.

Comment: @JeT_BluE You can put a break point inside the while loop and debug it, see what happens. If there is valid data, the session variable should be set correctly. Cheers

Comment: @DrakeVN Everything seems logical and fine. Its just if I removed the code fragment you have provided from my code, the `Response.Redirect(AppPage)` fires. If I leave that code fragment, nothing happens nothing loads no matter how many times I press it. I tried putting the code fragment in other sections in the code, but still the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) instead of ExecuteNonQuery() and ExecuteReader(). If D_O_B column in your database is datetime, you can just cast result to DateTime. If D_O_B column is varchar (or something similar), you have to use DateTime.Parse() to convert string to DateTime. Then just compare Day and Month parts of DateTime instances:

```
DateTime DOB = (DateTime)cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
DateTime Today = DateTime.Now;
if (Today.Month == DOB.Month && Today.Day == DOB.Day)
{
    //Happy Birthday
}
```

Comment: @Ňuf But the whole login button doesn't anything when pressed for any other users except for the one who's date of birth is same as system date ??

Comment: @Ňuf worked, forgot to put the Response.Redirect(AppPage) outside the if, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways, within in sql you can do a date compare between months and days using the attached page as a reference

[sql date compare (bad way for what you want to do)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx)

2) you can cast the incoming string to date time and do a system.datetime.month and system.datetime.day compare against the casted datetime from sql [c# better way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.month.aspx)

I would chose to do way number 2